# Ubuntu 18.04: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6 during cross platform compilation

Tags: 18.04, cross-compilation, crossplatform

I'm experience very strange error on Ubuntu 18.04 while doing cross compilation:

> "arm-hisiv400-linux-gnueabi-g++: error while loading shared libraries:
> libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory"

I've made sure that libstdc++.so.6 is in fact installed:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ ll trunk/artifacts/toolchain/arm3536/arm-hisiv400-linux/arm-hisiv400-linux-gnueabi/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      19 Jan 29 18:18 libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user user      19 Jan 29 18:18 libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user user 5206303 Jan 29 18:18 libstdc++.so.6.0.19*
```

Here is compilation error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/user/trunk/common/app/W32Linux'
arm-hisiv400-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -g -DNDEBUG -DARM  -I../W32Linux   -DLINUX -DLINUX_2_6 -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_GNU_SOURCE -I.. -ISrc  -ffast-math -fsigned-char -fauto-inc-dec -fcprop-registers -fdce -fdefer-pop -fdse -fguess-branch-probability -fif-conversion2 -fif-conversion -finline-small-functions -fipa-pure-const -fipa-reference -fmerge-constants -fsplit-wide-types -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch -ftree-copyrename -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts -ftree-dse -ftree-fre -ftree-sra -ftree-ter -funit-at-a-time -fomit-frame-pointer -fthread-jumps -falign-functions -falign-jumps -falign-loops -falign-labels -fcaller-saves -fcrossjumping -fcse-follow-jumps -fcse-skip-blocks -fdelete-null-pointer-checks -fexpensive-optimizations -fgcse -fgcse-lm -foptimize-sibling-calls -fpeephole2 -fregmove -freorder-blocks -freorder-functions -frerun-cse-after-loop -fsched-interblock -fsched-spec -fschedule-insns -fschedule-insns2 -fstrict-aliasing -fstrict-overflow -ftree-pre -ftree-vrp -std=c++0x -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mno-unaligned-access -fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations  -Wno-invalid-offsetof  -Wno-write-strings  -Wno-psabi -o arm3536_release/CriticalSection.o Src/CriticalSection.cpp
arm-hisiv400-linux-gnueabi-g++: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
../Makefile.rules:347: recipe for target 'arm3536_release/CriticalSection.o' failed
make[1]: *** [arm3536_release/CriticalSection.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/trunk/common/app/W32Linux'
Makefile.rules:359: recipe for target 'W32Linux' failed
make: *** [W32Linux] Error 2
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see any `-L` directives - so is the `trunk/artifacts/toolchain/arm3536/arm-hisiv400-linux/arm-hisiv400-linux-gnueabi/lib/` directory in the compiler's default library search path (as shown by `arm-hisiv400-linux-gnueabi-g++ -print-search-dirs`)?

Comment: @steeldriver I believe I fail during compilation stage and that is why you don't see -L directive.

The "trunk/artifacts/toolchain/arm3536/arm-hisiv400-linux/arm-hisiv400-linux-gnueabi/lib/" is not part of $PATH environment variable if you asked about it.

Comment: Ah good point - I missed the `-c`. I wonder if the issue is not about arm libraries, but is about the native libstdc++.so.6 being required by the `arm-hisiv400-linux-gnueabi-g++` executable itself? What does `ldd $(which arm-hisiv400-linux-gnueabi-g++)` return?

Comment: @steeldriver

`user@ubuntu:~$ ldd $(which arm-hisiv400-linux-gnueabi-g++)
 linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f48000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => not found
 libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7e29000)
 libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7e0b000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7c2f000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f4a000)
`

which is very strange because libstdc++.so.6 is definitely installed as I mentioned early.
See "ll trunk/artifacts/toolchain/arm3536/arm-hisiv400-linux/arm-hisiv400-linux-gnueabi/lib/" in my post.

Comment: You showed that the ARM version of `libstdc++.so.6` is installed - but the cross-compiler executable itself is a native (i386) application and needs the x86 version of the library

Comment: @steeldriver I see your point. However trying to install x86 version of lib:
  
    'user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++6  
    [sudo] password for user:   
    Reading package lists... Done  
    Building dependency tree         
    Reading state information... Done  
    libstdc++6 is already the newest version (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04).  
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.  
    '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119223/discussion-between-steeve007-and-steeldriver).